# How to remove unnecessary fields from autogenerated Swagger doc endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

Currently I have the following user model

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

And the following Auth Endpoint which receives an email and a password:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] User operatorParam) {
    var user = _userService.Authenticate(operatorParam.Email, operatorParam.Password);

    if (user == null) {
        return BadRequest(new {message = "Email or password is incorrect"});
    }

    return Ok(user);
}
```

Swagger auto-documentation is generating the following:

[image]

Is there any way I can remove the Id, name and token from the example? As only email and password are needed in this particular endpoint.

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: @Helen Swashbuckle

Comment: I would do it with a DocumentFilter, if you have that need for one model probably you will get the same for others one DocFilter can do what you need.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Reading about DocumentFilter I only found was to completely hide either an action or a variable. But not just for one endpoit. Could you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

**Create another model for the request body**

```
    public class UserRequest {
        public string Name { get; set; } //you can also remove this
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] UserRequest operatorParam) {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(operatorParam.Email, operatorParam.Password);

        if (user == null) {
            return BadRequest(new {message = "Email or password is incorrect"});
        }

        return Ok(user);
    }
```

There is an example you can follow this[Example](https://github.com/moinuliit1414/SocialMedia/tree/master/src)